# Sending ether from contract cause error

Tags: solidity, out-of-gas, wallet-transfer, revert-opcode

Hi In my contract I send ether from my contract to other address like `address.transfer(winnerAmount);`. It transfer ether successfully if my array have one address. If I have more than one address it throws `'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert'`. All other lines of code inside for loop works good if I comment `transfer`. I want to know what is the reason for this? I tried also adjusted gas limit, but it always fail. What is the better way to transfer the ether inside for loop? Thank you.

Comment: You should provide the code that's causing the error to get the best help.

Comment: Make sure you have ethers stored in your contract address. Code may help to debug.

Comment: Please provide the code that's causing the error for best help.

Comment: Sorry that was long time ago..Some how I moved on